# Javascript prototype confusion - correct way

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm creating an Javascript "class" with prototyping. I don't understand why the first/second block won't work, and the third block will work. For the first/second block I get: "Object # has no method 'validate' ". Why does it do that, and is block 3 the correct way?

**--Edit**
I have tested this in Chrome/FF

**--Edit2**
If I call the Test prototype with: 
var test = new Test();

And call the test var in de login prototype it will work....

**Block 1**

```
    function Test(){
        this.init();
    }

    Test.prototype.init = function(){
        $(".login").click(this.login);
    };

    Test.prototype.login = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        this.validate();

        console.log("login");
    };

    Test.prototype.validate = function(){
        console.log("validate");
    };

new Test();
```

**Block 2**

```
    function Test(){
        this.init();
    }

    Test.prototype.init = function(){
        $(".login").click(this.login);
    };

    Test.prototype.login = function(event){
        var self = this;
        event.preventDefault();

        self.validate();

        console.log("login");
    };

    Test.prototype.validate = function(){
        console.log("validate");
    };

    new Test();
```

**Block 3**

```
    function Test(){

    if(!(this instanceof LoginController)){
        return new LoginController();
    }

        self = this;

        this.init();
    }

    Test.prototype.init = function(){
        $(".login").click(this.login);
    };

    Test.prototype.login = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        self.validate();

        console.log("login");
    };

    Test.prototype.validate = function(){
        console.log("validate");
    };

    new Test();
```

Comment: All your three blocks works properly in my javascript console. Also note that in your block 3 you are **overwriting** the global variable `self`, which is never a good idea. I'd say that block 1 is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Test.prototype.init = function(){
  $(".login").click(this.login);
};
```

Here you're attaching `this.login` as event handler. Done this way, the function will have  it's `this` value reassigned by jquery to the element that triggered the event.

To to keep a reference to the `this` value you actually want, try:

```
Test.prototype.init = function(){
  var self = this;
  $(".login").click(function (evt) {
     return self.login(evt);
  });
};
```

or for browsers implementing [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
Test.prototype.init = function(){
  $(".login").click(this.login.bind(this));
};
```

or [`jQuery.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), which does the same thing as `bind`:

```
Test.prototype.init = function(){
  $(".login").click($.proxy(this.login, this));
};
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ilejiw/1/

---

**Update**: No, the 3rd variant is not the correct way, as every instance of `Test` would overwrite the same global `self` variable. So `self` would point to the last instance of `Test` (as long as it has not been overwritten by something else).

Comment: The init function can call the login, that works... But in the login prototype function I can't call the prototype validate function (chrome/FF). Why is this?

Comment: @AnnaSmother Are you using `self.validate();` in the login function? If yes, change it to `this.validate();`. If not, please provide a code example that does show the error. ;)

Comment: @AnnaSmother here is your fiddle updated, with what I wrote in the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/GSTfZ/1/

Comment: This was idd the cure for my problem, didn't do an hard refresh :P